# How do I change desktop background with a terminal command?

Tags: desktop

I trying to add to my [OS X configuration script](https://github.com/rudolph9/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx) a command which sets the background to the plain dark grey, however, when applied, it only sets it to the main monitor and any additional monitors currently connected keep their current background and any added thereafter still receive the default space background. What I have so far is as follows:

```
# Change Desktop default BackgroundColor to grey
defaults write com.apple.desktop '{ Background = { default = {BackgroundColor = ( "0.2549019753932953", "0.4117647111415863", "0.6666666865348816" ); Change = Never; ChangePath = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors"; ChangeTime = 1800; DrawBackgroundColor = 1; ImageFileAlias = <00000000 00ce0003 00000000 c73804cd 0000482b 00000000 000c2624 000c2633 0000ca1c 0a310000 00000920 fffe0000 00000000 0000ffff ffff0001 000c000c 2624000c 25fc000a 0789000e 00280013 0053006f 006c0069 00640020 00470072 00610079 00200044 00610072 006b002e 0070006e 0067000f 000c0005 006f0073 00780038 00360012 00394c69 62726172 792f4465 736b746f 70205069 63747572 65732f53 6f6c6964 20436f6c 6f72732f 536f6c69 64204772 61792044 61726b2e 706e6700 00130001 2f00ffff 0000>; ImageFilePath = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png"; NewChangePath = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors"; NewImageFilePath = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png"; NoImage = 0; Placement = Crop; Random = 0; }; }; }'
```

How do I set the default the the dark grey background via a terminal command?
How do I change all monitors already configured to grey via a terminal command?

Comment: That's a pretty useful set of commands! I also like your .aliases one too. Thanks!

Comment: I can't take all the credit, I forked it from [mathiasbynens](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles), I did add the keyboard, mouse, and non-working background settings though.

Comment: Ohh and my mouse tracking speed is set hight than system preferences will allow :() thats me screaming because it tracks fast.

Answer (score 28):

None of these other solutions work on Mavericks anymore because Apple moved the settings to a sqlite DB. But that's ok because now it's easier, the png can be anywhere in the filesystem, and all desktops (even virtual) are updated.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
 sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '/path/to/any/picture.png'";
 killall Dock;
```

Or, add it as a function to your ~/.bash_profile and call it as a terminal command with any non-relative path.

```
#   Update all Wallpapers
function wallpaper() {
    sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '$1'" && killall Dock 
}
```

`wallpaper ~/path/to/any/picture.png`

Comment: This is the only thing that works currently .

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown: thanks for you answer! Unfortunately this is not working in macOS Sierra anymore.. Do have an idea where Apple might now be saving which picture to use as wallpaper?

Comment: Do you know how to get it to centre/tile/fit to screen etc.?

Comment: @BenjaminHerzog The answer by Sanghyun Lee still works (on Mojave), just build from the GitHub source, not brew: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273628/1195

Comment: killall Dock breaks window placement on multi-desktop, so this can't be used with frequency

Comment: This did not work for me, and made Dock not start at all. I had to remove the database file to start Dock again.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS on macOS 11 (Big Sur).  It prevents the Dock from running and even survives an OS re-install.  Once I did `rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock`, the Dock instantly started.

Comment: PAY ATTENTION: It disables your dock and corrupt your desktop on macos Monterey!!!

Comment: Breaks MacOS ventura too!

Answer (score 21):

This should work for you:

```
osascript
tell application "Finder"
set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png"
end tell
```

There are several other ways on [this Mac Rumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=295558), but his way is the easiest.

Comment: Did you get this to work your self?  It didn't work for me.

Comment: gave me `./a.scpt:31:46: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png" to file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png". (-10006)`

Comment: Tried it again with a different color to see if it had something to do with the desktop already being set to dark grey and got `./a.scpt:31:46: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Medium.png" to file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Medium.png". (-10006)`

Comment: @KurtRudolph Try running it within AppleScript Editor. Does it work there? I did not try it, but I believe I have in the past.

Comment: Based upon @faraz's answer, it would appear that you need to tell Apple Script that you're supplying a POSIX path by including the POSIX keyword before the file keyword, e.g. `tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png"`

Comment: @JasonMusgrove Actually, I believe that's correct. Sorry I didn't have that originally!

Comment: Note that on newer macOSs (I'm currently on 12.4), the generic desktop pictures have moved. Now it's `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png`.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way to do it in one line:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Earth Horizon.jpg"'
```

Comment: The method of using `osascript` works for me only if I run `killall Dock` afterward. Does anybody else notice that?

Answer (score 12):

None of the solution mentioned worked for me on macOS 10.14.2 Sierra and I ended up with this AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell every desktop
        set picture to "path_to_wallpaper.jpg"
    end tell
end tell
```

It can be run from a terminal like that:

```
osascript path_to_applescript_file.scpt
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell every desktop to set picture to "path_to_wallpaper.jpg"'
```

Comment: Note: IIRC this only works if "Change Picture" is unchecked, so I might add to the "tell every desktop" block: `if get picture rotation is 1 then set picture rotation to 0`

Comment: This is a little better than the "tell application Finder" method. It changes the backgrounds of all visible desktops. So, it works on multiple monitors, unlike the Finder one. However, it doesn't change the backgrounds of desktops that aren't currently visible.

Comment: Interestingly, all of these `osascript` based solutions seem to pick a random picture for me on Ventura 13.1.  Even when I pick a file that doesn't exist, it sets a picture.  (M1 MBP)

My Wallpaper settings are set to randomly cycle through a folder of pics I have, and the `osascript` seems to be doing that, regardless of what picture I specify.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer installing a new application to making a new function, using [`m-cli`](https://github.com/rgcr/m-cli) is the way to go. It's easy to use, and it has lots of other useful features if you need.

```
brew install m-cli 
m wallpaper ./wallpapers/tree.jpg
```

`m-cli` auto detects the version of OS, [internally do the same things as other correct answers](https://github.com/rgcr/m-cli/blob/master/plugins/wallpaper) using `bash` script.

Comment: Thanks!! This one worked for me on macOS Mojave (though you need to get m-cli from the Github source, as the brew version is outdated from 2017)

Comment: On Catalina, brew version broke the OS, Dock gone, alt-tab gone, expose gone.  Needed to create a new user to fix

Answer (score 1):

The paths need to be properly referenced using `POSIX file` for `/posix/paths` or `as alias` with `Old:Mac:Style:Paths`.

Pick your poison...

POSIX path:

```
set desktopImage to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Dark.png"
tell application "Finder"
    set desktop picture to desktopImage
end tell
```

Mac path:

```
set localLibrary to path to library folder from local domain as string
set desktopImage to localLibrary & "Desktop Pictures:Solid Colors:Solid Gray Dark.png" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set desktop picture to desktopImage
end tell
```

You can easily turn any of the above Applescripts into a terminal command using `osascript [-e statement]`:

```
osascript -e 'set desktopImage to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Light.png"
tell application "Finder"
    set desktop picture to desktopImage
end tell'
```

To set multiple desktops, you can try something like `tell application "System Events" to set picture of every desktop to "<path>"`. Unfortunately, this seems to be broken in 10.7, so you'll end up getting the following error: `Expected class name but found application constant or consideration.`

Answer (score 1):

**NB:** As of Mojave, the below solution [does **not** work](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5829224#gistcomment-2725927).

---

Combining [jeremyjjbrown's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145174/28613) and [this Gist by willurd](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5829224), the most convenient way for El Capitan and up is as follows:

1. Open Automator (in Applications) and create a new Service
2. Set `Service receives selected` to `image files` at the top of the workflow. You can optionally limit it to only work in Finder.

[image: Sample image 1]

3. Add a `Run Shell Script` action to the workflow
4. Empty the default script and insert a slightly modified version of [jeremyjjbrown's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145174/28613) into the editor:

   ```
   read -e IMAGE;
   sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '$IMAGE'";
   killall Dock;
   ```
5. Save the service with a name of your choosing, for example `Set Desktop Picture on all Spaces`.

You can now right-click any image directly from Finder and choose the service from the context menu, easily setting the background for all desktops.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but it is by far my favorite (requires Python3):

I have always used `pywal` on all of my Linux machines, and I just wanted to see if it would also work on MacOS, and indeed it does.  Not only will it change the desktop image for all desktops with a single command, but it also has the ability to set your Terminal colors to a theme to match your desktop background (as long as you are using iTerm2 and not Terminal.app).

https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal/

I would suggest cloning it from the git repo and building it from source, as there is an issue with the current version on PyPI that does not include a fix to show the cursor location in iTerm2.

If you think it would be easier to install it from PyPI and patch the file, that is also an option -- just run `pip3 install pywal`, and then find the location of `sequences.py` in your `site-packages/pywal` directory (mine happened to be at `~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pywal/sequences.py`), and then just copy `sequences.py` from the master branch to your site-packages, and you are good to go.

My full installation went something like this:

```
$ pip3 install --user pywal
$ find /usr/local -type f -name "sequences.py"
(or)
$ find $HOME -type f -name "sequences.py"
> ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pywal/sequences.py
$ git clone https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal
$ cp pywal/sequences.py ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pywal/sequences.py
```

Then all you have to do to set the wallpaper for all desktops is run the following:

`wal -i $HOME/Pictures/Wallpapers/your_image.jpg`

...and bingo-bango it sets the wallpaper for ALL desktops AND gives you nice pretty matchy colors in iTerm2.

There are instructions in the pywal wiki on how to make the terminal colors persist across reboots by adding a line to `~/.bash_profile`.

So all that being said, while this method may take a bit more time to set up, in the long run, I find it by far to be the easiest and most satisfying.

Also, just a heads-up: `wal -i /path/to/image` does not work for some images, and I'm not sure why, but it worked for most of the images I tested.

Comment: As of August 2021, this should not be used on Big Sur. It will kill Dock. Your background will become black, your Dock will disappear, other elements of the UI will not work correctly.

There is a fix (https://github.com/dylanaraps/pywal/issues/581), but it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: That is not true.  I use the latest version of MacOS, and this works perfectly for me.

Comment: Perhaps it works for systems upgraded from a previous version.
On my completely new computer, it kills Dock, and a bunch of UI stuff stops working.

Answer (score 1):

On Monterey the command has slightly changed:

`osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell every desktop to set picture to \"/path/to/file/goes/here.jpg\" as POSIX file"`

Also for post-Monterey: I suspect you can look at [this file](https://github.com/rgcr/m-cli/blob/master/plugins/wallpaper) to see the "latest" way to do it, so long as `m-cli` stays a living project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `osascript` on macOS Monterey 12.4 to set the picture on every desktop such as:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell every desktop to set picture to \"/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Stone.png\" as POSIX file"
```

To find preinstalled desktop pictures for macOS Monterey:

```
find '/System/Library/Desktop Pictures' -not -path '*/.*'
```

To find preinstalled desktop pictures for macOS Big Sur:

```
find '/Library/Desktop Pictures' -not -path '*/.*'
```

If you prefer to make a script that's easier to read:

```
file="/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Stone.png"
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell every desktop to set picture to \"${file}\" as POSIX file"
```

Comment: Great, up-to-date answer +1

Answer (score 0):

A perl script to accomplish the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Cwd;

if ($#ARGV != 1) {
    die "\nUsage: ./changedesktop <filename> <startup disk> \nwhere <filename> may be    any JPEG, PNG, GIF, TIFF or PSD and <startup disk> is the name of your boot volume.\n\n";
}

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my $bootdisk = $ARGV[1];
my $directory = getcwd;
my $file = $bootdisk.$directory."/".$filename;
$file =~ tr/\//:/;
system("osascript -e \'tell application \"Finder\"\' -e \'set theFile to \"$file\"\' -   e     \'set desktop picture to \(theFile as alias\)\' -e \'end tell'");
```

Comment: No that is a perl script which executes running an osascript performing the same operation as the first post with a bunch of unnecessary perl code inputing the the image file which is to be set as the background.

Answer (score 0):

I use [`m-cli`](https://github.com/rgcr/m-cli) together with a little shell/apple script to change the wallpaper on all spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..16}; do
    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down'
    sleep 1
    m wallpaper $1
done
```